# "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records" error with Rails 5.2.1 and AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am currently deploying a EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 rails 5.2.1 server and have the following issue.
I get the following error when trying to access my S3 bucket.
"The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records".

I have place my access and secret keys in the `credentials.yml` file as follows.

```yml
EDITOR="subl --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
aws:
  access_key_id: Foo
  secret_access_key: bar
```

and added them to the `storage.yml` as

```yml
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id]
  secret_access_key: Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key]
  region: eu-west-2
  bucket: mybucket
```

I have run `rails console` to check their values and the return correctly
but receive the error when I upload an image to my bucket.

I have managed to get it to work successfully by adding the access and secret keys directly into the `storage.yml` file, but don't understand why when using the encrypted credentials I get the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say you  run "rails console" to check the values, are you doing that locally or on the EC2 instance? Have you also made sure the config/master.key is on your production server? That master.key probably (and shouldn't be) in your code repo and often is forgotten to get deployed.

Comment: Hi Nathan, yes I manually carried across the master.key. I also ran rails console on the EC2 instance "rail c production". As the both credentials where in plain text strings I assume that the master.key file is working fine. The returned value was encapsulated in quotes, so I was wondering is it doing the same when it presents it to AWS and therefore adding quotes as characters

Comment: @NathanKontny I figured it out by actually reading the storage.yml and place the secret.key inside ruby.
`access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>`